# Почему при первом использовании функции error = undefined (хотя ошибка есть), а при повторном использовании ошибка есть, почему так?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

> "@emotion/react": "^11.11.4",
> "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
> "@hookform/resolvers": "^3.3.4",
> "@mui/material": "^5.15.12",
> "@nestjs/common": "^10.0.2",
> "@nestjs/config": "^3.2.0",
> "@nestjs/core": "^10.0.2",
> "@nestjs/jwt": "^10.2.0",
> "@nestjs/platform-express": "^10.0.2",
> "@nestjs/swagger": "^7.3.0",
> "@nestjs/typeorm": "^10.0.2",
> "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.2.1",
> "@types/express": "^4.17.21",
> "ajv": "^8.12.0",
> "argon2": "^0.40.1",
> "axios": "^1.6.0",
> "bcrypt": "^5.1.1",
> "class-transformer": "^0.5.1",
> "class-validator": "^0.14.1",
> "localforage": "^1.10.0",
> "match-sorter": "^6.3.4",
> "mysql2": "^3.9.2",
> "pg": "^8.11.3",
> "react": "18.2.0",
> "react-dom": "18.2.0",
> "react-hook-form": "^7.51.0",
> "react-redux": "^9.1.0",
> "react-router-dom": "^6.22.3",
> "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
> "request": "^2.79.0",
> "rxjs": "^7.8.0",
> "sort-by": "^0.0.2",
> "tslib": "^2.3.0",
> "typeorm": "^0.3.20",
> "yup": "^1.4.0"

```
import React from 'react'
import { Box, Button, Grid, TextField, Typography, useTheme } from '@mui/material'
import { Controller, SubmitHandler, useForm } from 'react-hook-form'
import { formSchema } from '../features-SignUp/schema/schema'
import { yupResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/yup';
import { formBodyProps, submitButtonProps } from '../features-SignUp/styles/styles'
import { ISignUp, useSignUpMutation } from '@diary-app/shared';
import { ErrorComponent } from '../features-SignUp/components/ErrorComponent';


export const SignUp: React.FC = () => {

 const theme = useTheme()
 const [signUp, { isError, error }] = useSignUpMutation()

 const { control, handleSubmit, reset, formState: { errors } } = useForm<ISignUp>({
     mode: 'onChange',
     resolver: yupResolver(formSchema),
     defaultValues: {
         username: '',
         password: '',
         confirmPassword: ''
     }
 })
 const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<ISignUp> = async (data) => {
     await signUp(data)
     console.log(error)
     if(isError) {
         console.log(error)
     }
 }

 return (
     <Box
         sx={{ backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.default }}
         width='100vw'
         height='100vh'
         display='flex'
         justifyContent='center'
         alignItems='center'
     >
         <Box
             sx={formBodyProps}
             display='flex'
             justifyContent='center'
             alignItems='center'
             flexDirection='column'
         >
             <Typography marginBottom='5%' variant='h2'>Sign Up</Typography>
             <ErrorComponent error={error}/>
             <Box
                 width='100%'
                 component='form'
                 display='flex'
                 flexDirection='column'
                 justifyContent='center'
                 alignItems='center'
                 onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
             >
                 <Grid container width='100%' spacing={2} display='flex' alignItems='center' justifyContent='center'>
                     <Grid item xs={12}>
                         <Controller
                             control={control}
                             name='username'
                             render={({ field }) => (
                                 <TextField
                                     fullWidth
                                     color='secondary'
                                     label='Username'
                                     onChange={(e) => field.onChange(e)}
                                     value={field.value}
                                     error={!!errors.username}
                                     helperText={errors.username?.message}
                                 />
                             )}
                         />
                     </Grid>
                     <Grid item xs={6}>
                         <Controller
                             control={control}
                             name='password'
                             render={({ field }) => (
                                 <TextField
                                     fullWidth
                                     color='secondary'
                                     label='Password'
                                     type='password'
                                     error={!!errors.password}
                                     onChange={(e) => field.onChange(e)}
                                     value={field.value}
                                     helperText={errors.password?.message}
                                 />
                             )}
                         />
                     </Grid>
                     <Grid item xs={6}  >
                         <Controller
                             control={control}
                             name='confirmPassword'
                             render={({ field }) => (
                                 <TextField
                                     fullWidth
                                     type='password'
                                     label='Confirm password'
                                     color='secondary'
                                     error={!!errors.confirmPassword}
                                     onChange={(e) => field.onChange(e)}
                                     value={field.value}
                                     helperText={errors.confirmPassword?.message}
                                 />
                             )}
                         />
                     </Grid>
                 </Grid>
                 <Button type='submit' color="secondary" variant="outlined" sx={submitButtonProps}>Sign Up</Button>
             </Box>
         </Box>
     </Box >
 )
}
```

**api.ts**

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react'

export const authApi = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'authApi',
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/api/' }),
    tagTypes:['Users'],
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
       getUsers: builder.query({
            query: () => `users`,
            providesTags: ['Users']
       }),
       signUp: builder.mutation({
            query: (body) => ({
                url: `users`,
                method: 'POST',
                body: body
            }),
            invalidatesTags:['Users']
       })
    })
})

export const { useGetUsersQuery, useSignUpMutation } = authApi
```

**Первое использование функции (выдаёт что error = undefined, хотя ошибка есть)**
[image: 2]
**Второе использование функции (ну тут конечно же уже er)**
[image: 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

деталнее:

https://medium.com/search?q=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0+%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%85+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9+%D0%B8+%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B+%D0%B5%D0%B5+%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F+%D0%B2+React.+%D0%A7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C

```js
//это замыкание
const App = () => {
  //каждый ререндер создаст новую фукцию handler
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(0);

  //в момент создания функция запаминает свое лексическое окружение(state, и тд.)
  const handler = () => {
    setState((prev) => ++prev);
    //будет на 1 меньше актуального state всегда
    console.log(`старый стейт`, state);
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`актуальный стейт`, state);
  }, [state]);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handler}>update</button>
    </div> )
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(<App />);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: спасибо большое!